# openapi generator maven plugin fails

Tags: java

I am trying to generate api in a Spring project and I get:

```
[0:0]: unexpected error in Open-API generation
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

also I see IntelliJ complains in pom file for not finding dependencies like: surefire-junit-platform, junit-platform-surefire-provider, junit-jupiter-engine.

Is there a connection? How can I solve the Open API generation error?

Encoding file is ok

Comment: The problem is probably with/why don't you post your `inputSpec` !? ;)

Comment: what is inputSpec @xerx593

Comment: the "main input" (openapi.yaml/json/... file) for [this plugin](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/plugins/) (?)..

Comment: (it generates classes/endpoints for "your specification")

Comment: example: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/examples/multi-module/sample-schema/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml

Comment: It is really big file I cannot post it. To my team mates the error does not happens @xerx593

Comment: then...it sounds like ("my team mates...", StringIndexOutOfBoundsException) (yaml, is *very strict* regarding formatting/indent/whitespace), your formatting is broken (!?) (please *whitespace* compare with your team)

Comment: So maybe I should adjust intellij formatting

Comment: no idea .......

Comment: what you mean whitespace compare? @xerx593

Comment: i mean: force pull /use the same formatting as your colleagues.

Comment: I have checked and we use the same encoding, no idea what could be then

Answer (score 2):

So I found the reason for the string out of range. The error message is misleading because it refers to some issue in the api.yaml but the problem is in the path to the api.yaml (always a string for Java). I had the project folder with a space and this seems to cause all. So solution is to do not put space in name folder but an underscore.